# 400 Bad Request getting on AJAX Call

Tags: ajax, jquery

I try, when click the submit button then pass the ajax request with some values then calculate that values  and return.

**My Problem** : when I make custom Ajax Call then I get 400 error from admin-ajax.php.
Please help me to find my mistake or best way to do this.

**Ajax Call - footer.php(theme footer)**

```
 <script>
    $(function() {

       $("#calc_form").on("submit", function(e) { 
        //   alert("submit");
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: {
                    action: 'calculation',
                    message_id: $('#tot_tax_three_month_Input').val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (output) {

                }

            });
       });

    });
</script>
```

**Admin-ajax.php**

```
// handle the ajax request
 function calculation() {
     $value = $_REQUEST['message_id'];

     echo json_encode(array("value" => $value));
     die();
 }

     // register the ajax action for authenticated users
     add_action('wp_ajax_calculation', 'calculation');

     // register the ajax action for unauthenticated users
     add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_calculation', 'calculation');
```

**test.php**

```
  <form id="calc_form">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 40%" scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col">Per month LKR</th>
          <th scope="col">For 3 months period* LKR</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class=" text-danger"><b>Tax amount for 3 months</b></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" id="tot_tax_three_month_Input" class="form-control "  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit" id="btnCalculate" class="btn btn-success">Calculate</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnReset" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Did you add the `calculation()` function you admin-ajax.php? You’re not supposed to edit core files. Your code should be in functions.php of your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change files like @Chethan and @Jacob mention.I edit active theme's **functions.php** file instead of **wp-admin->admin-ajax.php**.Then change ajax **URL**

**footer.php**

```
  <script>
var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
jQuery(function() {

   jQuery("#calc_form").on("submit", function(e) { 
    //   alert("submit");
        e.preventDefault();

       jQuery.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'calculation',
                message_id: jQuery('#tot_tax_three_month_Input').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (output) {
                console.log(output);
            }

        });
   });

});
</script>
```

**function.php** before **admin-ajax.php**

```
   // register the ajax action for authenticated users
   add_action('wp_ajax_calculation', 'calculation');

  // register the ajax action for unauthenticated users
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_calculation', 'calculation');

  // handle the ajax request
  function calculation() {
     $value = $_REQUEST['message_id'];
     $value = 1 + 1;
     echo json_encode(array("value" => $value));
     die();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have to use full url of ajax function. I have use `ajax_url` in your **Ajax Call - footer.php(theme footer)** file code.

```
<script>
    var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
    jQuery(function() {

       jQuery("#calc_form").on("submit", function(e) { 
        //   alert("submit");
            e.preventDefault();

            jQuery.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: 'calculation',
                    message_id: jQuery('#tot_tax_three_month_Input').val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (output) {

                }

            });
       });

    });
</script>
```

Remove code from **wp-admin->admin-ajax.php** file and Add that code in your active theme's **functions.php** file instead of **wp-admin->admin-ajax.php**

```
// handle the ajax request
 function calculation() {
     $value = $_REQUEST['message_id'];

     echo json_encode(array("value" => $value));
     die();
 }

 // register the ajax action for authenticated users
 add_action('wp_ajax_calculation', 'calculation');

 // register the ajax action for unauthenticated users
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_calculation', 'calculation');
```

Comment: Nothing change still got same error

Comment: I have tested your code and made above changes and it is working fine. can you tell me where did you include Admin-ajax.php file in your theme ??? I have add Admin-ajax.php file code in my theme's functions.php file.

Comment: @Rika Did you modify core Admin-ajax.php file ?  or Admin-ajax.php file is your custom file in theme ? you can use calculation() code of Admin-ajax.php file code in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: I did it wp-admin->admin-ajax.php file

Comment: You’re not supposed to edit wp-admin->admin-ajax.php file as @JacobPeattie  it is core file. Remove code from admin-ajax.php file and Add that code in your active theme's functions.php file instead of wp-admin->admin-ajax.php.

Comment: guys thank you so much help me.it's work now

Comment: I have edited my answer with clarification. Thanks!